# How do I duplicate the blue Waldo's routine with the red one?

Tags: spacechem

I have a reactor for which I'd like to double the throughput by using both Waldos to perform the same routine.  While they can't be exact duplicates, I'd like to start the blue Waldo routine off by duplicating the red one.  What's the easiest way to apply the blue Waldo's routine with the entirety of the red's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple.
First, make sure there is nothing on the blue waldo, this would only get in the way. Then:

1. Select the whole red waldo path.
2. Use ctrl+drag to copy the entire red waldo path.
3. Then right click the result, and click blue layer.
4. Move the entire thing to the right location.

Make sure not to deselect the parts between step 2 and 3, as the correct stuff is already selected. Also, if the red path covers the entire screen, this will be a lot harder. Do it in steps and add parts manual where needed. Using shortcuts to place commands is quick too.

Edit: If red covers 100% screen, there is still a way to copy half of it into blue like this:

1. Select half the screen.
2. Right click it and select blue layer.
3. ctrl+drag the blue layer to the other half of the screen.
4. Select the original half again and right click to make it red.
5. Either hide or lock red by clicking in the lower right at layer controls.
6. Move the blue part back to the original location.
7. Repeat with half of the remaining half.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; unfortunately sometimes when duplicating the red path you can conflict with other red instructions already in the reactor, and the copy will fail. So while this does work some of the time, it's not 100%...

Comment: Oops, part of my message got cut off. I know this wont work on huge waldo paths, but when red covers 2/3rd of the screen, you can still copy 1/3, make it blue, and then copy the other 1/3. Sometimes you will need to fill some space in-between manually. I know it's not perfect, but it's the closed you get :)

Comment: Btw, if red covers 100% of the screen. You can make half of it blue, copy the blue thing to the left, then make the first part red again. At least you got half the thing copies in 6 clicks. You can repeat this again with half the remaining part, so you have 75% coverd. After that you probably want to fill in the last 25% manually with shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for the info; yikes -- I wish there was an easier way!

Answer (score 1):

I have not found any way to do this automatically -- I have always just manually reproduced the red waldo's routine.  It does go pretty fast with the red for reference, fortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyboard controls for quick and easy placement of commands and arrows.  When duplicating Waldo paths, trace over and place the general commands (In β, Drop/Grab, etc.), then perform appropriate revisions (In α, Grab, etc.) on another pass.